# getDownloadUrl() error after updating firebase

Tags: java, android

help me to find a solution.. error on getdownloadurl after updaing firebase
error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()

this is my code

```
private void upload() {
    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading ");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(new StringBuilder("images/").append
            (UUID.randomUUID()).toString().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                saveUriToCategory(categoryIdSelect, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(UploadWallpaper.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                    .getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Upload: "+(int)progress+"%");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using approach which is `deprecated` and removed in newer version of Firebase Storage. To get url of uploaded file you need to run another query inside `onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)`for example:

```
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                       String imageUrl = uri.toString(); //image url

                    }
                })
```